# Get the character of a JLabel in Java

Tags: java, jlabel

I have a JLabel array that contains many words. I am trying to get the first character of the words. In fact I am trying to get all the character, but if I see how to get the first, I will get the others.

I tried this

```
mport java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingConstants;
import javax.swing.border.EtchedBorder;
import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;

public class WordSearchFrame extends JFrame {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private static final int COLS_IN_WORDLIST = 1;


    private static final int FRAME_WIDTH = 640;


    private static final int FRAME_HEIGHT = 480;


    private JLabel[][] wordSearch;


    private JLabel[] wordListLabels;


    private JPanel wordListPanel;


    private JPanel wordsearchPanel;


    private JPanel rightSidePanel;


    private JPanel leftSidePanel;


    private JPanel searchButtonPanel;


    private JButton searchButton;


    private int numRows;


    private int numCols;


    private ActionListener searchButtonListener;

    private ArrayList<String> wordList;

    class SearchListener implements ActionListener {

        private int x = 0;

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event) {
            wordListLabels[0].setForeground(Color.BLACK);
            if (x == 0) {
                findword(x);
                x++;
            } else {
                wordListLabels[x - 1].setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                findword(x);
                x++;
            }


        }

        private void findword(int x) {
            wordListLabels[x].setForeground(Color.RED);
            findword2(x);

        }

        private void findword2(int x) {
            for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
                wordSearch[x + i][x].setForeground(Color.RED);

        }
    }

    private void buildLeftSidePanel() throws WordSearchException, IOException {

        leftSidePanel = new JPanel();
        leftSidePanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        leftSidePanel.setBorder(new TitledBorder(new EtchedBorder(), "Word Search"));


        wordsearchPanel = new JPanel();
        wordsearchPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(numRows, numCols));
        leftSidePanel.add(wordsearchPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);


        this.getContentPane().add(leftSidePanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    }


    private void initGridFromFile(String wordSearchFilename) throws WordSearchException, IOException {
        this.numRows = 0;
        this.numCols = 0;
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(wordSearchFilename));
        String line = reader.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line, " ");
            if (this.numCols == 0) {
                this.numCols = tokenizer.countTokens();
            } else {
                if (tokenizer.countTokens() != this.numCols) {
                    throw new WordSearchException("Invalid number of columns in word search");
                }
            }
            line = reader.readLine();
            this.numRows++;
        }
        reader.close();
        this.wordSearch = new JLabel[numRows][numCols];
    }


    protected void loadGridFromFile(String wordSearchFilename) throws IOException {
        int row = 0;
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(wordSearchFilename));
        String line = reader.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line, " ");
            int col = 0;
            while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
                String tok = tokenizer.nextToken();
                wordSearch[row][col] = new JLabel(tok);
                wordSearch[row][col].setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                wordSearch[row][col].setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                wordsearchPanel.add(wordSearch[row][col]);
                col++;
            }
            line = reader.readLine();
            row++;
        }
        reader.close();
    }


    private void buildRightSidePanel() {

        rightSidePanel = new JPanel();
        rightSidePanel.setBorder(new TitledBorder(new EtchedBorder(), "Word List"));
        rightSidePanel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());


        wordListLabels = new JLabel[wordList.size()];
        wordListPanel = new JPanel();
        wordListPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(wordList.size(), 1));
        for (int i = 0; i < this.wordList.size(); i++) {
            // If the line below won't compile in Java 1.4.2, make it
            // String word = (String)this.wordList.get(i);
            String word = this.wordList.get(i);
            wordListLabels[i] = new JLabel(word);
            wordListLabels[i].setForeground(Color.BLUE);
            wordListLabels[i].setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
            wordListPanel.add(wordListLabels[i]);
        }
        rightSidePanel.add(wordListPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);


        searchButton = new JButton("Search");
        searchButtonListener = new SearchListener();
        searchButton.addActionListener(searchButtonListener);
        searchButtonPanel = new JPanel();
        searchButtonPanel.add(searchButton);
        rightSidePanel.add(searchButtonPanel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);


        this.getContentPane().add(rightSidePanel, BorderLayout.EAST);
    }

    private void loadWordList(String wordListFilename) throws WordSearchException, IOException {
        int row = 0;

        wordList = new ArrayList<String>();
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(wordListFilename));
        String line = reader.readLine();
        while (line != null) {
            StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(line, " ");
            if (tokenizer.countTokens() != COLS_IN_WORDLIST) {
                throw new WordSearchException("Error: only one word per line allowed in the word list");
            }
            String tok = tokenizer.nextToken();
            wordList.add(tok);
            line = reader.readLine();
            row++;
        }
        reader.close();
    }


    public WordSearchFrame(String wordSearchFilename, String wordListFilename) throws IOException, WordSearchException {
        this.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
        this.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.initGridFromFile(wordSearchFilename);
        buildLeftSidePanel();
        this.loadGridFromFile(wordSearchFilename);
        loadWordList(wordListFilename);
        buildRightSidePanel();
    }


    public WordSearchFrame(String[][] wordSearch, String[] wordList) throws IOException, WordSearchException {
        this.setSize(FRAME_WIDTH, FRAME_HEIGHT);
        this.getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());
        this.numRows = wordSearch.length;
        this.numCols = wordSearch[0].length;
        this.wordSearch = new JLabel[this.numRows][this.numCols];
        buildLeftSidePanel();
        for (int row = 0; row < this.numRows; row++) {
            for (int col = 0; col < this.numCols; col++) {
                this.wordSearch[row][col] = new JLabel(wordSearch[row][col]);
                this.wordSearch[row][col].setForeground(Color.BLACK);
                this.wordSearch[row][col].setHorizontalAlignment(SwingConstants.CENTER);
                this.wordsearchPanel.add(this.wordSearch[row][col]);
            }
        }

        this.wordList = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < wordList.length; i++) {
            this.wordList.add(wordList[i]);
        }
        buildRightSidePanel();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            if (args.length != 2) {
                System.out.println("Command line arguments: <word search file> <word list>");
            } else {
                WordSearchFrame frame = new WordSearchFrame(args[0], args[1]);
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

I have all the next:

1. the panel on the left hand side, which consists of the word search
2. the contents of the word search into the JLabels of the word search grid in the GUI
3. Now I just need the `jlabe[index].charAt(0)`. That does not work.

I tried `jlabe[index].getText().charAt(0)`. That does not work.

What I tried above works fine, but not for what I want it.

Also the other class

```
public class WordSearchException extends RuntimeException {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

public WordSearchException() {

}

public WordSearchException(String reason) {
    super(reason);
}
```

}

Comment: Your question appears to assume that we have powers that don't exist, such as seeing code not shown. Please consider creating a valid [mcve] and adding this code to your question, so that we can try to run the code and see the error for ourselves.

Comment: I am sorry I do not put it, because I thought the question is too clear to add more code. But there it is.

Comment: I hope that it's clear enough for you to get an answer, but if none are forthcoming, please consider my request

Comment: I did it, thanks. Do you see my problem after posting more code?

Comment: @Noel - I don't think your question is as **"too clear"** as you might think. Where exactly in your code are you trying to get the first character of a JLabel caption (text)? I merely ask so that I don't have to look through all that code. It may also clear up as to which array you're actually talking about.

Comment: I know that is why I did not put any more code. Well, What is think is that i have a jlabel array. private JLabel[] wordListLabels; then I instantiate it like this wordListLabels[i] = new JLabel(word); after that I have my array of wordListLabels. Now I can get the text with .getText(), but I would like to be able to get the characters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way to do that is to gettext().charat(index)